# Android: Error installing an apk from Downloads folder

Tags: android, parsing, download, download-manager

I am downloading files from server using the DownloadManager class as mentioned [here](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/). The image downloaded can be accessed from the *Downloads* folder on android. When I click the downloaded image from the *Downloads*, the image is displayed. But if it try to downlaod an apk instead of an image, the downloaded apk cannot be installed from the *Downloads* folder, a `problem parsing the package` error appears. Why?

Here is what I am doing (the same as mentioned in the link above):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Query;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DownloadManagerActivity extends Activity {
    private long enqueue;
    private DownloadManager dm;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                   /* long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);*/
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                          /*  ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            String uriString = c
                                    .getString(c
                                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                            view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));*/
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/MyApp.apk"));

        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);

    }

    public void showDownload(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the APK using https? If so, is the SSL certificate from a valid certificate authority (Verisign, Thawte, etc.)?

Comment: I am downloading the apk using http and not https

Comment: Does this happen with all APK's? Or just this specific one?

Comment: Have you looked in the logcat to see if there is more detail for the error?

Comment: I will edit my question and show my code.